# Differentiating content links from permalinks

Tags: css, hyperlink, permalinks

Have successfully made change to Wordpress blog hyperlink colors so that link and visited are the same color. However, the permalinks - date and name (atop the posts) and category and 'comments' at the foot of posts have also been affected. Specifically, they now become blue when visited. I wanted them to stay their default color (grey, visited or not).

Is there a way to differentiate all links, except permalinks?

Wordpress theme is Twenty Ten.

Additional CSS I used is:

```
a:content-link {
    color: #0066cc;
}
a:visited {
color: #0066cc;
}
a:hover {
color: #ff4b33;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you created is affecting all links because you are selecting all the `a` tags. For instance, `a:visted {}` is selecting every single `a` tag in the markup. If you only want certain links to change color then you should add a class to the links you want to change color and then select those in the CSS instead of the `a` tags.

For example you can add a class of 'checkVisited' to an anchor tag in the HTML

`<a class="checkVisited" href="https://www.somewhere.com">Click Here</a>`

And then in the CSS you can select this by doing

```
.checkVisited:visited {
  color: #0066cc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Very much appreciated, Michael. The CSS I posted above does not in fact alter the color of permalinks. They remain default grey. The theme default for their unvisited color holds. They only become #0066cc when clicked/visited. Also: the checkVisited solution creates a link without the default hover color.

Comment: OK, it seems to be a contest between my Additional CSS idea and parent theme's default. It's giving me half of what I want. The following neutralised the default and works - giving me one color post links and unaltered (actually, affirmed) meta and category/comments links:

    /* visited link */
    a:visited {
      color: #0066cc;
    }
    a:hover {
    color: #ff4b33;
    }
    .entry-meta a, .entry-meta a:visited {
        color: #777;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .cat-links a:visited {
        color: #777;
    }
    .comments-link a {
    color: #777;
    }